# Where do you get Python SOAPPy forwindows?

Tags: python, soappy

I can't seem to install it, computer doesn't know what to open it with, is there something wrong? Do you know a website where I can install it?

Answer (score 0):

SOAPPy is now part of Python Web Services. You can get it from the Python Web Services [page at sourceforge](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/).